# Fetching embedded-entry-block data from contentful in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, contentful

I wanted to fetch data from contentful and I used rich text data type. But I always get the undefined when I tried to call the data from the object. Can someone explain what should I do?

```
<div
          v-for="facilitator in currentEvent.fields.facilitators"
          :key="facilitator"
          class="columns facilitators"
        >
          <img
            class="column is-2 facilitator-photo"
            src="~assets/img/imam_wahyudi.jpg"
          />
          <div class="column is-10 facilitator-desc">
            <p class="facilitator-name">
              {{ facilitator.name }}
            </p>
            <p class="facilitator-occ">{{ facilitator.occupation }}</p>
            <p class="class-overview">{{ facilitator.overviewKelas }}</p>
            <p>{{ test(facilitator) }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I also printed the data structure in console and here is the result:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
-0:
--content: (...)
--data: Object
---target: Object
----fields: Object
-----classOverview: (...)
-----name: (...)
-----occupation: (...)
-----photo: (...)
```

I expect to get the value in classOverview, name, occupation, and photo

Comment: `facilitator in currentEvent.fields.facilitators`, can you show `currentEvent.fields.facilitators` data structure?

Comment: @ittus currentEvent is the name of props which is an entry in contentful, fields is used to access field in an entry, and facilitators is the name of field with rich text as data type. Can you please help me?